# Explanation of Scala construct

Tags: scala, self-type

I am busy with a major refactoring task on some legacy Scala/Akka code, and am being haunted by a construct that I am unable to explain, which is hampering my effort:

```
trait PerRequestCreator {
  this: Actor =>
  def perRequest(<some_params>): ActorRef = { body of function }
}
```

Which is then used as such:

```
class SomeActor extends PerRequestCreator with Actor {
  def processRequest: Route = {
    perRequest(<some_params_passed>)
  }
}
```

I am having trouble understanding the `this: Actor => ...` part of the trait.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called *self-type*, and it expresses a requirement for the `PerRequestCreator` to be mixed in into something that extends `Actor`.

It's useful because now you can use anything defined in `Actor` inside the definition of `PerRequestCreator` and the compiler will check that you can only extend `PerRequestCreator` if you also extend `Actor`.

Example:

```
class SomeClass extends PerRequestCreator            // this won't compile
class SomeClass extends PerRequestCreator with Actor // this is ok
```

You can read more about it here: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/self-types.html